# Android getLocationOnScreen always return 0 when called in ListView's onScroll callback

Tags: android

```
    lv_msg.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            //do nothing
        }
        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if (v_filter_gender == null) {
                return;
            }
            v_filter_gender.getLocationOnScreen(header_location);
            int y = header_location[1];
            ......
        }
    });
```

the variable "y" is correct on 4.4.4 and 5.0.2 so far but on 4.1.2 it is always 0.

I tried to use onGlobalLayoutListener, but still can't get correct location.

Any idea?

Comment: Also I found that when I kill app and then start it, everything is fine. When I close it by pressing back button on home activity and open it again(so Application is not re-created), it's incorrect...so weird!

Comment: What is your `v_filter_gender`? and it's a static variable?

Comment: @Minhtdh No, it's a normal view. Seems this is relevant with a bug of ViewPager on 4.1.2...and looks like I solved it...and I don't know what part of code I changed worked...